# %orig found outside of hook or subclass

Tags: ios

I'm using Rpetrich's Theos repository and I'm using `tweak.xmi` for making tweak on multiple files for easier in management.

I can build and run successfully except one thing: I cannot use  `hookf`. Before that, when I put all source code inside one `tweak.x`, everything works normal. But now, everytime I compile, I meet this error:

```
error: %orig found outside of hook or subclass
```

One example of my hook is:

```
%hookf(int, uname, struct utsname *value) {
    int ret = %orig;
    strcpy(value->machine, getModelIdentifier());
    strcpy(value->nodename, getHostname());
    return ret;
}
```

**Update:**

Here is my tweak that using `MSHookFunction`

```
#import "substrate.h"

static int (*original_gethostname)(char *, size_t);

static int replace_gethostname(char *value, size_t valueLen) {
    int ret = gethostname(value, valueLen);
    if (value) strcpy(value, "thao");
    return ret;
}

%ctor {
    %init(_ungrouped)
    MSHookFunction((void*)gethostname, (void*)replace_gethostname, (void**)&original_gethostname);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [theos/theos](https://github.com/theos/theos) instead of [rpetrich/theos](https://github.com/rpetrich/theos)?

Comment: yes. I have tried. but looks like original theos doesn't support xmi file. I compile and meet error :( There are some sources tell me that use `Rpetrich` fixes this problem.

Comment: Could you use multiple `*.x` files instead of `*.xmi`?

Comment: Can you tell me how to use multiple `*.x` files? just include in `Makefile` ?

Comment: If all of those `*.x` are independent, just put all of them into your `tweakname_FILES` setting.

Answer (score 3):

You should give the newer [theos/theos](https://github.com/theos/theos) a try, perhaps it has fixed this bug already.

---

`*.xmi`/`*.xi` support was [broken](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreakdevelopers/comments/3ujcpv/issue_with_splitting_project_up_across_multiple/) (seems still is), and the lead developer [discourages its usage](https://github.com/theos/theos/issues/141#issuecomment-203125047), and including a source file instead of header file [is strange anyway](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreakdevelopers/comments/4892ez/errors_in_using_new_theostheos_for_older_tweak/). If you just want to separate the hooks into different files, simply put all the `*.xm`/`*.x` and into the _FILES setting:

```
tweakname_FILES = first.x second.x third.x
```

Comment: Very thanks for pointing me to github's discussing. I found out many useful information here :D

Comment: The bug from official theos still be here. As in discussing, `xi/xmi` files have some advantages in management. But your option is suitable with me currently.

Comment: @hqt I'm using the master version theos/theos and no "%orig outside" error. Have you `#include <sys/utsname.h>`, and could you check if there's any unbalanced `%hook`/`%group`?

Comment: I have changed to original theos version. Using multi tweak files. But If I use `hookf` function, I still meet the same error. But when I move to `MSHookFunction`, I can compile and run successfully. Nevertheless, everytime I open any apps, it will close permantly as it has crashed.

Comment: I have added my tweak code that caused crash. Please take a look

Comment: @hqt Your replaced `gethostname` calls `gethostname` again which leads to infinite recursion. You should call `%orig` (`original_gethostname`) instead.